# split() in google sheets changes to numeric

Tags: split, google-sheets

I've a cell in a google sheet with the following: `=transpose(split( "01 02 03"," ")`. I expect, because it's text that it will keep the leading zeros (0). However, I end up with cells that are obviously numeric as it has removed the leading zero: <1> <2> <3>

In fact, this problem occurs at the level of each individual value. If I use instead `=transpose(split( "01 02A 03"," ")` I get <1> <02a> <3>.

Now, before you ask, YES the cells are formatted as "plain text".

There are two questions, the first one rhetorical: WHY google?

The second real question: **Is there a way to force split() to keep the leading zeros?** or alternatively **Can I prevent sheets from treating the output of split() as potentially numerical?**

Comment: Why do you want leading zeros in the first place?

Comment: You're thinking about my ultimate problem and maybe solving that instead. To summarize, I've got a set of answers that people provide to a survey result. These answers to be counted have to align a set of provided answers. these answer choices sometimes have leading zeros to keep numerical ordering in downstream uses. 

In other words, there are some thorny issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering a tick mark before each number:

```
=transpose(split( "'01 '02 '03"," "))
```

Comment: yes, but then I end up with ticks in each result which will not match on a vlookup.

Comment: Have you tried it? I have no tick marks after the split. Formatted as automatic or plain text.

Comment: WAIT. my bad. you said "tick", not "backtick"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without function or formula would be to apply to `01 02 03` Data > Split text to columns...  with Space as Separator and then Copy and Transpose its output.